# Is this C user input code vulnerable?

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

I have this code that reads input from the user:

```
unsigned int readInput(char * buffer, unsigned int len){
    size_t stringlen = 0;
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        if(stringlen < (len-1)){
            buffer[stringlen] = c;
            stringlen++;
        }
    }
    buffer[stringlen+1] = '\x00';
    return stringlen;
}
```

The size of char * buff is already set to len and has been memset to contain "0"s. Is this code vulnerable to any vulnerability attacks?

Comment: How long will this code run if I feed it 12 TB of data? What if I just hook it up to `/dev/zero`?

Comment: This is just a function, and why cout isn't a C function, this is C code

Comment: Well like any input if you feed it 12 TB of data it would take a very long time to run but it wouldn't be vulnerable would it? It would just take a very long time, it trashes data that is more than the length

Comment: @KerrekSB mistype, count was supposed to be stringlen

Comment: Why downvoted downvoter? It's a valid question...

Comment: It automatically casts to char no?

Comment: Not really a valid question for here tho - should be over on the code review site surely

Comment: Sorry I didn't know where to put it

Comment: Just don't use stdio.h and you'll be fine. Nobody would write a console program for professional use nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the platform, `unsigned int` might be too small to hold the number `13194139533312`. You should always use `size_t` for  buffer sizes in C, not doing so might be a vulnerability, yes.

Also, of course `getchar()` doesn't return `char`, so that's broken too.

I'd say "yes", that code is vulnerable.

Comment: Well the unsigned int is defined by me, I have a buffer length of 60. char name [60]; memset(name,0,60); readInput(name,60);

Comment: Statically defined in the code, would that still be vulnerable?

Comment: Well no, I guess it's safe to assume that 60 is in range of `unsigned int`, but that's not clear from the function's prototype so that's not what I was trying to answer.

Comment: Oh ok, can size_t overflow if the input is really big?

Answer (score 1):

Your code potentially writes out of bounds and leaves an array element uninitialized:

```
char buf[10];  // uninitialized!

readInput(buf, 10);   // feed 12 TB of data
```

This has undefined behaviour because you write to `buf[10]`.

```
readInput(buf, 10);  // feed 8 bytes of data

strlen(buf);
```

This has undefined behaviour because you read the uninitialized value `buf[8]`.

The error lies in the way you assign the null terminator, which uses the wrong index. It should say:

```
buffer[stringlen] = '\0';
//     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Because you compute `len - 1`, your code should also have a precondition that `len` must be strictly positive. This is sensible, because you promise to produce a null-terminated string.

Comment: Don't think the null terminator is a problem, if(stringlen < (len-1)) solves that. Since it's < len-1. So if len was 60 (max index 59), it would assign max to index 58, then null terminate on 59

Comment: @bi0phaz3: Your current code would null-terminate on 60, because the previous `stringlen++` means that `stringlen` already has value 59.

Comment: I just now see that @KerrekSB and I are making the same claim.  We are both right :-P

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the buffer is allocated `len` bytes, the most glaring problem is:

```
buffer[stringlen+1] = '\x00';
```

This is because the loop can exit with `stringlen` equal to `len-1`, and therefore you are writing to `buffer[len]`.  However, you should only be writing to indices up to `len-1`.

So let's fix this as follows:

```
buffer[stringlen] = '\x00';
```

This is what you really want because you have not written to `buffer[stringlen]` yet.

A subtler error is that if len is 0 (which you probably would say should never happen), then `len-1` is MAXINT and hence `(stringlen < (len-1))` is always true.  Thus, the code will always buffer overflow on a 0 length buffer.

Comment: Ah but the final value of stringlen will be len-2 because < len-1 in the loop

Comment: @bi0phaz3: Nope, the loop exits when `stringlen` is **equal to** `len-1`.

Comment: Ah, if I were to run it and keep it as +1, what would happen to the memory?

Comment: @bi0phaz3 You be writing past the end of the buffer.  You might get a core dump, or maybe it would just write something on the heap without crashing.

Comment: I ran it and I didn't get a segmentation fault signal from the program, so I presume its the latter then

Comment: Output `stringlen` to verify my claim that it is past the end of the buffer.

Comment: @bi0phaz3: If *that* is your approach to programming in C, then you have a *long* way ahead of you and a lot to learn :-(

Comment: Well I usually go about programming in C++, I was just wondering if a technique like this to prevent a buffer overflow or maybe an integer overflow from atoi would work

Answer (score -1):

Your question is whether or not the code is vulnerable to attacks. The answer is no, it is not vulnerable, certainly not by the common definitions of vulnerability.

This is an interface between some unknown input (possibly by an adversary) and a buffer. You have correctly included a mechanism that prevents a buffer overflow, so your code is safe. [We assume here that everything from getchar() down is not subject of your question].

Whether the code will work as intended is a different story, (others already pointed out the hole before the terminating NULL), but that was not your question.

Comment: Note that while this function itself is not vulnerable, if misused, the system may become vulnerable (e.g, when passed in length larger than the buffer).

Comment: To the downvoter et al.: vulnerability, i.e., susceptibility to attacks is not synonymous with correctness. The OP asked about the former, but most responses address the latter. Would a specially-crafted input allow an attacker to take over the machine where this code runs? Read about gets/fgets. Why does fgets use int (and not size_t like snprintf)? Because it does not matter; the code above would not be vulnerable even if it defined len as an unsigned char. Does the code "char buf[16]; fgets(buf, 256, stdin);" make fgets to be a vulnerable interface?